# How to create a pandas data frame with specific columns from multiple text files?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 100s of text files that have a header row and then a series of numbers in each column (example below):

Textfile 1

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 0.001 | 5.45 |
| 0.23 | 6.83 |
| 0.03 | 4.86 |

Textfile 2

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 0.003 | 7.34 |
| 0.89 | 3.89 |
| 0.45 | 5.66 |

I would like to create a new pandas data frame (example below) that contains the values in column 2 of each file as a new column that has the name of the text file.

| Textfile 1 | Textfile 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 5.45 | 7.34 |
| 6.83 | 3.89 |
| 4.86 | 5.66 |

I was thinking along the lines of a for loop that loops through all the text files in the folder and at each iteration adds a column to the new data frame (something like the code below)

```
all_files=glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.txt"))

df_ppm = []

for file in all_files:
    file_name = os.path.split(file)[1]
    df_ppm.append(pd.read_csv(file_name))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need :)

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\dane\Documents\pythonPlayground\csv_files' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")  # this is a file filter so you only read csv files

new_df = pd.DataFrame()  # create a new empty dataframe 

for file_path in all_files:  # loop through each file 
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)  # get the file name 
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col=None, header=0)  # read a file and add it to a dataframe 
    new_df[file_name] = df['y']  # assuming the column is always called 'y' you can just add it to the new DF this way, otherwise, use df.iloc[1]

print(new_df)
```

Comment: I've noticed that when I try and run this code for multiple files that I get the following error: /var/folders/73/w7l5gwm10c78zpw07w1kkw44wghycn/T/ipykernel_77719/3951885623.py:6: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead.  To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  df1[file_name] = df['ppm'].copy()

Comment: @Anne good call and nice find!

Answer (score 0):

You can read only the columns of files using `usecols` in read_csv since the column name('y') is the same in all the .txt files

```
all_files=glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.txt"))

df_ppm = {}

for file in all_files:
    file_name = os.path.split(file)[1]
    df_ppm[file_name[:-3]] = pd.read_csv(file_name, usecols=['y'])['y'].to_list()

df_ppm = pd.DataFrame(df_ppm)
```